# How to monitor AMD GPU on Linux Server

Tags: centos, gpu, amd-graphics

I am working on a linux server and need to monitor the gpu load of an AMD GPU. Unfortunately I do not have super user rights so I cannot install radeontop. Is there another way to monitor amd gpu load?

System Info:

```
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch:cxx-4.1-amd64:cxx-4.1-noarch:desktop-4.1-amd64:desktop-4.1-noarch:languages-4.1-amd64:languages-4.1-noarch:printing-4.1-amd64:printing-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core) 
Release:    7.4.1708
Codename:   Core
```

Answer (score 5):

As a simple user you can acces to  `/sys/class/drm/` which gives you many informations about all the gpus in your system.
They are listed as `card0` `card1` and so on..

I'm using Radeon VII as a simple user you can get many informations from your GPU.
`cat /sys/class/drm/card0/device/gpu_busy_percent` gpu core usage.
`cat /sys/class/drm/card0/device/mem_busy_percent` gpu memory usage.
`cat /sys/class/drm/card0/device/mem_info_vram_used` memory used.

Under `/sys/class/drm/card*/device/hwmon/hwmon*/` many more informations are available such as temperature, voltage, frequency

I strongly recommend to you to get a tour of the `/sys/class/drm` directories and see all informations you can read as user.